# jQuery rounded corners with border in IE

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with my website in IE8 (6 and 7 also I guess).

My main div has rounded corners. I did that with jQuery.corners - this works fine in Firefox en also IE!

The problem is: in IE I don't see the (white) borders... Does someone know why? Or is it nog supported?

The site is: http://77.243.237.196/~ksaatom/newsite

It would be great if the border would work! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the LiquidCanvas jQuery plugin instead.  It is a fully cross-browser (IE6/7/8, FF, etc) library that lets you do rounded-corners and borders.  I've had similar problems with jQuery Corners in IE, but everything's worked for me since I switched to it.

There is a write-up on how to use it for both corners and borders at http://www.caffeinedi.com/2009/11/02/using-jquery-and-liquidcanvas-to-add-drop-shadows-borders-rounded-corners-and-other-effects-to-your-website-even-in-ie6-and-ie7/

Answer (score 1):

[Curvycorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) is my favorite rounded corner plug-in so far.  It gracefully degrades if the browser natively supports rounding corners (most modern browsers can do this through CSS).

Another huge bonus is there is no JavaScript required (except for including a reference to the curvycorner file itself).  All you have to do is add the appropriate CSS to your element and if it's not natively supported to do it automatically then curvycorners steps in.

Comment: Looks nice! Definitely going to try this one to! Thanks!